# Jquery Mobile geolocation. Issues with IP address

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, mobile

Im creating a mobile site using Jquery mobile. The user is required to enter their location into a text box.

To make this easier, i want to use geolocation to find their location for them.

My understanding is that when no gps function is available (like on most laptops for example) the geolocation service will use their IP adress as well as wifi signals in the area to come up with a location. This is terrible. That tells me that the computer im at is 9 miles away from way i actually am....

Ive run the site on my iPhone and it found my location perfectly. This is because it uses the gps function in the phone.

So, what i want to do: Somehow check if the users device (iPhone, Android, Laptop, Pc) has gps. If so, use geolocation to find their location. If, not skip geolocation search and enter location manually.

Answer (score 1):

Geolocation api won't give you anything about the method used to provide the user position (Unless you use some underlying framework like phonegap). May be you should deal with accuracy parameter to check whether the position will be acceptable.